# Disable prepared statements on a per-query basis in DBIx::Class with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbix-class

I have a few queries which are much slower when using prepared statements in Postgres (this is a known issue, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html). I therefore want to turn off statement preparation for these queries.

in DBIx::Class, I can turn off prepared statements globally when connecting to the database by passing the parameter "pg_server_prepare => 0" in the connect_info. but I can't see how to change this for an existing connection. given a DBIx::Class::Schema, I tried this:

```
$schema->storage->connect_info->[0]->{'pg_server_prepare'} = 0;
```

if I log the connect_info after that call, I see the new value for this parameter, but the database driver still uses prepared statements. I also tried to disconnect and reconnect

```
$schema->storage->connect_info->[0]->{'pg_server_prepare'} = 0;
$schema->storage->disconnect;
$schema->connect(@{ $schema->storage->connect_info->[0] });
```

but this didn't help either.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using DBD::Pg, so I can't say for sure, but this -might- be working:

```
$schema->storage->dbh_do(sub {
    my (undef, $dbh) = @_;
    local $dbh->{pg_server_prepare} = 0;
    # now do anything with $dbh you want
});
```